# Make asynchronous function calls and use async/await

Tags: node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I am trying to figure out how to make asynchronous function calls **and use async/await**.  This could be useful when breaking up long processes.  The best solution I have been able to come up with is written below.  Is there a better way of doing this?

**NB**  This is a contrived example.  The question isn't about how to handle long running processes.  It's about making "asynchronous function calls and use [of] async/await".

```
async function callAsync(fn) {
    let args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setImmediate(() => {
            try {
                resolve(fn(...args))
            }
            catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        })
    })
}

async function longProcessPart1(x) {
    return x;
}

async function longProcessPart2(x) {
    return x;
}

(async function fn() {

    try {
        let result = await callAsync(longProcessPart1, 1);
        result = await callAsync(longProcessPart2, result);  // Use the result of longProcessPart1 in longProcessPart2.
        console.log(result);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}())
```

Comment: That is the way to go indeed. Just note, long processes if they can't be done in parallel, if one depends on the result from the previous, then there's no benefit in making them async so you just await for them one by one.

Comment: @MadaManu  Does the setImmediate allow for other processes to potentially run between each longProcessN?  I am trying to allow other processes to potentially run between longProcess1 and longProcess2 if such a process were to be queued.

Comment: I do not particularly like the word "potentially". What runs when and where is the sequence. If one was to allow processes to run between other processes one would loose the flow of execution. The idea is, if there are other processes that you do not depend on their result to kick off another process then they could get executed. Imagine 3 processes a,b,c (all returning corresponding values). If computing c is dependant on a but not on b. A&B process can happen in parallel, but C ONLY after A.

Comment: @MadaManu  One reason I made longProcess1 and longProcess2 async functions is that they too may await on asynchronous processes (this is the scenario in the actual use case).

Comment: @MadaManu  After the first setImmediate, is it correct that a callback could be added to the Poll queue if, for example, a HTTP Server (e.g., the native http module) were running?  And, could the callback added to the Poll queue execute between longProcess1 and longProcess2?

Comment: yes that's correct. And as I said there's if process 2 depends on process 1 result it will not happen in parallel. So adding this http call or whatever (this is like process 3) if it doesn't depend on p1 or p2 results it  will get executed in between, in parallel, at some other time as such.

Comment: So, long processes should just NEVER be run in the main node.js Javascript thread in any sort of server that needs to be responsive.  Rather than trying to let something momentarily run in the middle, the much, much, much better way to do things is to use [Worker Threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) or create a work queue and some worker processes (which can be nodejs programs of their own).

Comment: There are many, many advantages to nodejs cooperative single threading and asynchronous I/O design, but running some long process is NOT one of them.  You really need to keep them out of any type of thread that needs to be responsive to incoming events.  With Worker Threads now, it should work great to shunt the long running things over to a Worker Thread and let some other CPU munch on it for awhile.

Comment: The example is contrived.  And, the longProcess isn't long anymore because it has been broken up into two short processes.  :-)

Comment: Well 1/2 long !== short for event loop purposes.  So, if this is already all figured out, then what is the open question?  FYI, unless you use `setTimeout()` with at least a few ms of time, it's still easy to starve the event  queue with `setImmediate()` only because not everything gets a fair chance to run with `setImmediate()`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be one way. however I would suggest to use node's promisify. However this you only need to do if your longProcesses are sync, else you can directly await them(I can see longProcesses are async)

```
 const {promisify} = require('util');
 const delay = promisify(setImmediate);

(async function fn() {

    try {
        await delay();
        let result = longProcessPart1(1);
        await delay();
        result = longProcessPart2(result);  // Use the result of longProcessPart1 in longProcessPart2.
        console.log(result);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}())
```

EDIT: here's a working example:

```
const longProcessPart1 = () => {
  let i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {}
  console.log('longProcessPart1 done returning', i);
  return i;
};

const longProcessPart2 = i => {
  for (; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
  console.log('longProcessPart2 done returning', i);
  return i;
};

(async function fn() {
  try {
    await delay();
    let result = longProcessPart1(1);
    await delay();
    result = longProcessPart2(result); // Use the result of longProcessPart1 in longProcessPart2.
    console.log(result);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
})();
```

if your longProcesses are CPU intensive, then I suggest use [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html). which is stable in current LTS.

Comment: @`Abhishek chandel`  The API states that promisify, "takes a function following the common error-first callback style".  However, I can't think of any reason for why this wouldn't work.  Can you?

Comment: @stackhatter I missed a paranthesis. check out the working code I posted.